# SharePoint Online Document Library File Upload Customization

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx

I am looking for ways to customize File Upload behavior for Document Library instead of default OOB behavior. By customization, I mean extracting few metadata from file name, take few inputs from user and few validations. I wanted to know if this is feasible in SharePoint Online Modern experience sites. Any guidance in this regard is very much appreciated. Thank you.